# How to make "LIKE" query work in MongoDB?

Tags: php, sql, mongodb, sql-like

I have a list of street names and I want to select all that start with "Al".
In my MySQL I would do something like

```
SELECT * FROM streets WHERE "street_name" LIKE "Al%"
```

How about MongoDB using PHP?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
db.streets.find( { street_name : /^Al/i } );
```

or:

```
db.streets.find( { street_name : { $regex : '^Al', $options: 'i' } } );
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions

Turning this into PHP:

```
$regex = new MongoRegex("/^Al/i");
$collection->find(array('street_name' => $regex));
```

Comment: Yes but how about in php? $database->streets->find(array("street" => "/^Al/i"));

Comment: As a side question, how does this compare in terms of raw speed? The thought of using regular expressions to filter a data set makes me cringe a little... Complete newbie at mongodb though.

Comment: As long as the regex starts with ^ (i.e. match against the beginning of the string), indexes will be used.

Answer (score 3):

See: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart

Also, highly recommend just using the native mongodb connector from PHP instead of a wrapper. It's way faster than any wrapper.

http://php.net/class.mongodb

Answer (score 2):

here is my working example:

```
<?php
use MongoDB\BSON\Regex;
$collection = $yourMongoClient->yourDatabase->yourCollection;
$regex = new Regex($text, 's');
$where = ['your_field_for_search' => $regex];
$cursor = $collection->find($where);
//Lets iterate through collection
```

Answer (score 1):

`$collection.find({"name": /.*Al.*/})`

or, similar,

`$collection.find({"name": /Al/})`

You're looking for something that contains "Al" somewhere (SQL's '%' operator is equivalent to regexps' '.*'), not something that has "Al" anchored to the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

MongoRegex has been deprecated.
Use [MongoDB\BSON\Regex](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-regex.php)

```
$regex = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex ( '^A1');
$cursor = $collection->find(array('street_name' => $regex));
//iterate through the cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$mongoObj = new MongoClient();
$where = array("name" => new MongoRegex("^/AI/i"));
$mongoObj->dbName->collectionName->find($where);
?>
```

[**View for more details**](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.sqltomongo.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this

```
['key' => ['$regex' => '(?i)value']]
```